# How to simplify $2^{a\left(2^{bc}-1\right)}-1\mod{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

How to simplify $$2^{a\left(2^{bc}-1\right)}-1\mod{N}$$

Where a,b,c are big integers with relatively small primes and N is a big integer that is hard to factor(it does not have small primes).

I have been trying doing the following:

$$2^{a\left(2^{bc}-1\right)}-1\mod{N}=$$
$$2^{a^{\left(2^{bc}-1\right)}}-1\mod{N}=$$
$$2^{\frac{a^{2^{bc}}}{a}}-1\mod{N}=$$
$$4^{\frac{a^{bc}}{a}}-1\mod{N}=$$

I don't know how to continue from here. Is there somehow a way to apply mod $N$ on just one part of $4^{\frac{a^{bc}}{a}}-1\mod{N}=$

Comment: What this has to do with calculus?

Comment: $a(2^{bc}-1)\ne a^{(2^{bc}-1)}$

Comment: @MMS why are you saying this?

Comment: $4=3+1$; $4^{\frac{a^{bc}}{a}}-1 mod N= 3k mod N$